# React native sends empty req.body and undefined req.file to nodejs multer

Tags: node.js, react-native, multipartform-data, multer, react-native-image-picker

Im using react-native and nodejs(multer). In nodejs I receive `req.body-{}`, `req.file-undefined` and `req.files-undefined`

I checked everything in stackoverflow and nothing works. Here is my code.

**Client code**(react native):

```
const onPressOpenLibrary = async () => {
        const result = await launchImageLibrary({
            maxHeight: 200,
            maxWidth: 200,
            selectionLimit: 0,
            mediaType: 'photo',
            includeBase64: true
        })

        if (result.assets) {
            const formData = new FormData()

            formData.append('name', 'Alexander')
         
            formData.append('avatar', {
                uri: result.assets[0].uri,
                type: result.assets[0].type,
                name: result.assets[0].fileName
            })

            setResult(result)

            axios.post('upload-image', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data;`
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

**Server code**(nodejs):

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json())
...
const upload = multer({
    dest: 'uploads/'
})

router.post(
    '/upload-image',
    upload.single('avatar'),
    async (req: Request, res: AppResponse, next: NextFunction) => {
        console.log('upload image body', req.body) // -> {}
        console.log('upload image files', req.files) // -> undefined
        console.log('upload image file', req.file) // -> undefined
    }
)
```

**What I tried**:

- in react native when I pick and safe in state the response I have  `<Image source={{ uri: result.assets[0].uri }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />` and image is displayed properly.
- from postman everything working
- from axios and fetch on the client side not working

**What could be the problem and eventually the solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**:
Cant send text or image `FormData` from `react native` with axios or fetch.

**Solution**:
Downgraded axios to `axios: ^0.24.0`.

Answer (score 0):

`result.assets[0].uri` return a reference of a local cached image on device memory but you can not directly upload that image raw data to a remote server.

You should either upload the image as `base64` or `BLOB` data.

Comment: I saw some tutorials that works my way but I want to upload the image from nodejs to `Cloudinary`. Can you please provide more information how to achive it with `base64` or `BLOB`?

Comment: Also I have text data that is not passed in `req.body` - `formData.append('name', 'Alexander')`

Comment: set `includeBase64` to `true` in `react-native-image-picker`  to get `base64` image raw data. Cloudinary has native support for base64

Comment: I changed it but no difference. Look also that I append key/value text in form data and still body is empty and file/s are undefined. But from postman I can send text data.

Comment: From postman I can sent image and text. So the problem is 100% in react-native code. And probably not in image-picker but in axios, FormData or some android tricks.